# SQL Select TableName, ColumnName and ColumnValue

Tags: sql

I have an error in MSCRM with an activity entity. I have the activity guid but unfortunately multiple entities are considered activities so it could be on any of those tables, including maybe custom tables. So I am wanting to so an SQL query to select the TableName, ColumnName and ColumnValue where ColumnName is like '%id'. I have this which is selecting the columns by the name but I can not figure out how to get the value from this

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%id' 
order by TABLE_NAME
```

I do not have permissions to create proceedures

Comment: The information_schema just stores meta data, you won't get the values in the tables from this. Query the actual tables...

Comment: I need to query the table name as well though. It needs to be get the tablename and column name of any column with a name matching '%id'

Comment: Sorry and the value of 'something'

Comment: write a dynamic query from the result of your info_schema query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little dynamic SQL may help.

You may notice that I excluded Views to avoid redundant information (I use a naming convention for views) ... `Table_Name not like 'vw_%'`  You could exclude views with a join to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables`

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)
Set @SQL=Stuff((Select 'Union All ' +Expr 
                 From  (
                        Select Expr  = 'Select Table_Schema='''+Table_Schema+''',Table_Name='''+Table_Name+''',Column_Name='''+Column_Name+''',Value=cast('+Column_Name+' as varchar(max)) From '+quotename(Table_Schema)+'.'+quoteName(Table_Name)+' '
                         From  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                         Where COLUMN_NAME like '%id' 
                           and Table_Name not like 'vw_%'
                       ) A
                 For XML Path ('')),1,10,'')
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]